# Remove tuple-pair in set that are already present in another tuple

Tags: python, duplicates, set, tuples

I have a set

Ex:

```
{(2, 3, 7, 8), (1, 3), (4, 6), (4, 8), (1, 2, 3), (1, 6), (7, 8), (1, 6, 8), (3, 5)}
```

But when a tuple-pair is already in another tuple I want to remove it.

ex:
`(7, 8)` is in `(2, 3, 7, 8)`, `(1, 3)` is in `(1, 2, 3)` and 
`(1, 6)` is in `(1, 6, 8)`

So the set becomes:

```
{(2, 3, 7, 8), (4, 6), (4, 8), (1, 2, 3), (1, 6, 8), (3, 5)}
```

The order of the elements in the tuple doesn't matter and you should always keeps the longest sequence.

How do you do that?

Comment: Only tuple-*pairs*, or tuples with an arbitrary amount of numbers?

Comment: Do order and position matter? Eg, would `(8, 7)` or `(2, 8)` get removed?

Comment: Why does `(1, 3)` stay since there is a `(1, 2, 3)`? Does order matter?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis: I think because `(1,3)` is first...

Comment: and it should keep the _longest_ sequence right?

Comment: When you post a question kindly explain the input of your question.

Comment: @user138770: please make you question more specific. Currently there are a lot of "unclear aspects"...

Comment: The best i can do is O(n^2)..

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Hopefully, the OP understands that a set is intrinsically an unordered collection...

Comment: @PM2Ring: based on most questions I see here (and the quality of this question), I seriously doubt that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a very efficient solution (O(n^2); traversing the set twice) but I am not sure we can do much better here.

```
my_set = {(2, 3, 7, 8), (1, 3), (4, 6), (4, 8), (1, 2, 3), (1, 6), (7, 8), (1, 6, 8), (3, 5)}

remove = set()
for i in my_set:
    for j in my_set:
        if i != j and all(f not in remove for f in (i, j)):
            if all(x in j for x in i):
                remove.add(i)

res = my_set - remove
print(res)  # {(2, 3, 7, 8), (4, 6), (4, 8), (1, 2, 3), (1, 6, 8), (3, 5)}
```

Notice that it converts the inner tuples to sets and that puts some limitations on it (no duplicate elements on the tuples)

Answer (score 1):

We can do the test more efficiently by converting the tuples to sets, and then afterwards converting the sets back to tuples. I use frozensets because they're immutable, like tuples.

```
src = {
    (2, 3, 7, 8), (1, 3), (4, 6), (4, 8), (1, 2, 3), 
    (1, 6), (7, 8), (1, 6, 8), (3, 5)
}

temp = [frozenset(u) for u in src]
temp.sort(key=len, reverse=True)

dest = []
for t in temp:
    if not any(t <= u for u in dest):
        dest.append(t)

dest = {tuple(sorted(u)) for u in dest}
print(dest)
```

**output**

```
{(2, 3, 7, 8), (4, 6), (4, 8), (1, 2, 3), (1, 6, 8), (3, 5)}
```

---

We first convert the tuples to sets and store them in a list, sorting the list items by length, from longest to shortest. We then add each list item into the `dest` list only if it's not a subset of an existing item. Then we use a set comprehension to convert the sets back to ordered tuples.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
from pprint import pprint

S = {(2, 3, 7, 8), (1, 3), (4, 6), (4, 8), (1, 2, 3), (1, 6), (7, 8), (1, 6, 8), (3, 5)}

V = {frozenset(s) for s in S}

W = {x for x in V if not any(x <= y for y in V - {x})}

pprint(W)
```

Output

```
set([frozenset([4, 8]),
     frozenset([3, 5]),
     frozenset([2, 3, 7, 8]),
     frozenset([4, 6]),
     frozenset([1, 6, 8]),
     frozenset([1, 2, 3])])
```